# How can we JOIN two Spark SQL dataframes using a SQL-esque "LIKE" criterion?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

We are using the PySpark libraries interfacing with Spark 1.3.1.

We have two dataframes, `documents_df := {document_id, document_text}` and `keywords_df := {keyword}`.  We would like to JOIN the two dataframes and return a resulting dataframe with `{document_id, keyword}` pairs, using the criteria that the keyword_df.keyword appears in the document_df.document_text string.

In PostgreSQL, for example, we could achieve this using an ON clause of the form:

`document_df.document_text ilike '%' || keyword_df.keyword || '%'`

In PySpark however, I cannot get any form of join syntax to work.  Has anybody achieved something like this before?

With kind regards,

Will

Comment: You could close the question with accepting the answer which will encourage others to answer questions! Also you can keep open and update the question if you have still some question :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible in a two different ways but generally speaking not recommended. First lets create a dummy data:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

document_row = Row("document_id", "document_text")
keyword_row = Row("keyword") 

documents_df = sc.parallelize([
    document_row(1L, "apache spark is the best"),
    document_row(2L, "erlang rocks"),
    document_row(3L, "but haskell is better")
]).toDF()

keywords_df = sc.parallelize([
    keyword_row("erlang"),
    keyword_row("haskell"),
    keyword_row("spark")
]).toDF()
```

1. Hive UDFs

   ```
   documents_df.registerTempTable("documents")
   keywords_df.registerTempTable("keywords")

   query = """SELECT document_id, keyword
       FROM documents JOIN keywords
       ON document_text LIKE CONCAT('%', keyword, '%')"""

   like_with_hive_udf = sqlContext.sql(query)
   like_with_hive_udf.show()

   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |document_id|keyword|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |          1|  spark|
   ## |          2| erlang|
   ## |          3|haskell|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ```
2. Python UDF

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col 
   from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

   # Of you can replace `in` with a regular expression
   contains = udf(lambda s, q: q in s, BooleanType())

   like_with_python_udf = (documents_df.join(keywords_df)
       .where(contains(col("document_text"), col("keyword")))
       .select(col("document_id"), col("keyword")))
   like_with_python_udf.show()

   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |document_id|keyword|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |          1|  spark|
   ## |          2| erlang|
   ## |          3|haskell|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ```

Why not recommended? Because in both cases it requires a Cartesian product:

```
like_with_hive_udf.explain()

## TungstenProject [document_id#2L,keyword#4]
##  Filter document_text#3 LIKE concat(%,keyword#4,%)
##   CartesianProduct
##    Scan PhysicalRDD[document_id#2L,document_text#3]
##    Scan PhysicalRDD[keyword#4]

like_with_python_udf.explain()

## TungstenProject [document_id#2L,keyword#4]
##  Filter pythonUDF#13
##   !BatchPythonEvaluation PythonUDF#<lambda>(document_text#3,keyword#4), ...
##    CartesianProduct
##     Scan PhysicalRDD[document_id#2L,document_text#3]
##     Scan PhysicalRDD[keyword#4]
```

There are other ways to achieve a similar effect without a full Cartesian.

1. Join on tokenized document - useful if keywords list is to large to be handled in a memory of a single machine

   ```
   from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer
   from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

   tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="document_text", outputCol="words")

   tokenized = (tokenizer.transform(documents_df)
       .select(col("document_id"), explode(col("words")).alias("token")))

   like_with_tokenizer = (tokenized
       .join(keywords_df, col("token") == col("keyword"))
       .drop("token"))

   like_with_tokenizer.show()

   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |document_id|keyword|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |          3|haskell|
   ## |          1|  spark|
   ## |          2| erlang|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ```

   This requires shuffle but not Cartesian:

   ```
   like_with_tokenizer.explain()

   ## TungstenProject [document_id#2L,keyword#4]
   ##  SortMergeJoin [token#29], [keyword#4]
   ##   TungstenSort [token#29 ASC], false, 0
   ##    TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(token#29)
   ##     TungstenProject [document_id#2L,token#29]
   ##      !Generate explode(words#27), true, false, [document_id#2L, ...
   ##       ConvertToSafe
   ##        TungstenProject [document_id#2L,UDF(document_text#3) AS words#27]
   ##         Scan PhysicalRDD[document_id#2L,document_text#3]
   ##   TungstenSort [keyword#4 ASC], false, 0
   ##    TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(keyword#4)
   ##     ConvertToUnsafe
   ##      Scan PhysicalRDD[keyword#4]
   ```
2. Python UDF and broadcast variable - if keywords list is relatively small

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

   keywords = sc.broadcast(set(
       keywords_df.map(lambda row: row[0]).collect()))

   bd_contains = udf(
       lambda s: list(set(s.split()) & keywords.value), 
       ArrayType(StringType()))


   like_with_bd = (documents_df.select(
       col("document_id"), 
       explode(bd_contains(col("document_text"))).alias("keyword")))

   like_with_bd.show()

   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |document_id|keyword|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ## |          1|  spark|
   ## |          2| erlang|
   ## |          3|haskell|
   ## +-----------+-------+
   ```

   It requires neither shuffle nor Cartesian but you still have to transfer broadcast variable to each worker node.

   ```
   like_with_bd.explain()

   ## TungstenProject [document_id#2L,keyword#46]
   ##  !Generate explode(pythonUDF#47), true, false, ...
   ##   ConvertToSafe
   ##    TungstenProject [document_id#2L,pythonUDF#47]
   ##     !BatchPythonEvaluation PythonUDF#<lambda>(document_text#3), ...
   ##      Scan PhysicalRDD[document_id#2L,document_text#3]
   ```
3. Since Spark 1.6.0 you can mark a small data frame using `sql.functions.broadcast` to get a similar effect as above without using UDFs and explicit broadcast variables. Reusing tokenized data:

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

   like_with_tokenizer_and_bd = (broadcast(tokenized)
       .join(keywords_df, col("token") == col("keyword"))
       .drop("token"))

   like_with_tokenizer.explain()

   ## TungstenProject [document_id#3L,keyword#5]
   ##  BroadcastHashJoin [token#10], [keyword#5], BuildLeft
   ##   TungstenProject [document_id#3L,token#10]
   ##    !Generate explode(words#8), true, false, ...
   ##     ConvertToSafe
   ##      TungstenProject [document_id#3L,UDF(document_text#4) AS words#8]
   ##       Scan PhysicalRDD[document_id#3L,document_text#4]
   ##   ConvertToUnsafe
   ##    Scan PhysicalRDD[keyword#5]
   ```

**Related**:

- For approximate matching see [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/1560062).

Comment: This is an excellent and helpful reply.  Thank you for taking the time to write something so comprehensive.  Not only have you answered my question, but I learned quite a few other things that I didn't know you could do.  I'm going to use the variable broadcast method, since the keyword list will be small.  Problem solved!

Comment: OK.  One problem, @zero323.  The `explode()` function was introduced only in Spark 1.4.  I'm stuck (for now) with 1.3.1.  Is it possible to embed the UDF into a `map()` function to return multiple rows (i.e. one per matching keyword) for each row of input?

Comment: Solved it!  For reference: `like_with_bd= documents_df.select(
    col("document_id"), 
    bd_contains(col("document_text")).alias("keyword")).flatMap(lambda row: [(kw, row[0]) for kw in row[1]])`

Answer (score 0):

Precise way of doing this is as below:(Bit slow but accurate)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

from pyspark.sql import Row


def string_match_percentage(col_1, col_2, confidence):
    s = col_1.lower()
    t = col_2.lower()

    global row, col
    rows = len(s) + 1
    cols = len(t) + 1
    array_diffrence = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)

    for i in range(1, rows):
        for k in range(1, cols):
            array_diffrence[i][0] = i
            array_diffrence[0][k] = k

    for col in range(1, cols):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            if s[row - 1] == t[col - 1]:
                cost = 0
            else:
                cost = 2
            array_diffrence[row][col] = min(array_diffrence[row - 1][col] + 1,
                                            array_diffrence[row][col - 1] + 1,
                                            array_diffrence[row - 1][col - 1] + cost)
    match_percentage = ((len(s) + len(t)) - array_diffrence[row][col]) / (len(s) + len(t)) * 100
    if match_percentage >= confidence:
        return True
    else:
        return False


document_row = Row("document_id", "document_text")
keyword_row = Row("keyword")

documents_df = sc.parallelize([
    document_row(1, "google llc"),
    document_row(2, "blackfiled llc"),
    document_row(3, "yahoo llc")
]).toDF()

keywords_df = sc.parallelize([
    keyword_row("yahoo"),
    keyword_row("google"),
    keyword_row("apple")
]).toDF()

conditional_contains = udf(lambda s, q: string_match_percentage(s, q, confidence=70), BooleanType())

like_joined_df = (documents_df.crossJoin(keywords_df)
                        .where(conditional_contains(col("document_text"), col("keyword")))
                        .select(col("document_id"), col("keyword"), col("document_text")))
like_joined_df.show()
```

Output:

```
# +-----------+-------+-------------+
# |document_id|keyword|document_text|
# +-----------+-------+-------------+
# |          1| google|   google llc|
# |          3|  yahoo|    yahoo llc|
# +-----------+-------+-------------+
```