# Spark SQL case insensitive filter for column conditions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I use Spark SQL filter as a case insensitive filter?

For example:

```scala
dataFrame.filter(dataFrame.col("vendor").equalTo("fortinet"));
```

It just returns rows that `'vendor'` column is equal to `'fortinet'`, but I want rows that `'vendor'` column equal to `'fortinet'` or `'Fortinet'` or `'foRtinet'` or ...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can either use case-insensitive regex:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1L, "Fortinet"), (2L, "foRtinet"), (3L, "foo")
)).toDF("k", "v")

df.where($"v".rlike("(?i)^fortinet$")).show
// +---+--------+
// |  k|       v|
// +---+--------+
// |  1|Fortinet|
// |  2|foRtinet|
// +---+--------+
```

or simple equality with `lower` / `upper`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lower, upper}

df.where(lower($"v") === "fortinet")
// +---+--------+
// |  k|       v|
// +---+--------+
// |  1|Fortinet|
// |  2|foRtinet|
// +---+--------+

df.where(upper($"v") === "FORTINET")
// +---+--------+
// |  k|       v|
// +---+--------+
// |  1|Fortinet|
// |  2|foRtinet|
// +---+--------+
```

For simple filters I would prefer `rlike` although performance should be similar, for `join` conditions equality is a much better choice. See [How can we JOIN two Spark SQL dataframes using a SQL-esque "LIKE" criterion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33168970/1560062) for details.

Comment: @zero3232  I have this problem with all table. I mean I need that my application provides case insensitive result. is there any solution with which i can get SQLServer like results (where it ignores case everytime) ?

Comment: For Pyspark `lower` is available via `from pyspark.sql.functions import lower`.

Comment: For future viewers confused by the `(?i)` as I was, that is the syntax for Scala regex flags ([case-insensitivity in this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57119261)).

Comment: dataFrame.filter(dataFrame.col("vendor").rlike("(?i)^fortinet$"))

Answer (score 21):

Try to use lower/upper string functions:

```
dataFrame.filter(lower(dataFrame.col("vendor")).equalTo("fortinet"))
```

or

```
dataFrame.filter(upper(dataFrame.col("vendor")).equalTo("FORTINET"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which saves a couple of sets of parenthesis:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.filter(f.upper("vendor") == "FORTINET)
```