# Is spark sql like case sensitive?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Looks like spark sql is case sensitive for "like" queries, right ?

```
spark.sql("select distinct status, length(status)  from table")
```

Returns

```
Active|6

spark.sql("select distinct status  from table where status like '%active%'")
```

Returns no value

```
spark.sql("select distinct status  from table where status like '%Active%'")
```

Returns

```
 Active
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894372/spark-sql-case-insensitive-filter-for-column-conditions

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Spark is case sensitive. Most of the RDBMSs are case sensitive by default for string comparison. If you want case-insensitive, try rlike or convert the column to upper/lower case.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("Active"),("Stable"),("Inactive")).toDF("status")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [status: string]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")

scala> df.show
+--------+
|  status|
+--------+
|  Active|
|  Stable|
|Inactive|
+--------+


scala> spark.sql(""" select status from tbl where status like '%Active%' """).show
+------+
|status|
+------+
|Active|
+------+


scala> spark.sql(""" select status from tbl where lower(status) like '%active%' """).show
+--------+
|  status|
+--------+
|  Active|
|Inactive|
+--------+


scala>
```

Comment: A default install of SQL Server will give you a case insensitive default collation in my experience. So your second sentence isn't true.

Comment: '@Damien.. not sure about SQL Server..I'll edit that sentence