# Spark SQL - rlike ignore case

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark SQL and trying to compare a string using `rlike` it works fine, however would like to understand how to ignore case.

**this return true**

```
select "1 Week Ending Jan 14, 2018" rlike "^\\d+ Week Ending [a-z, A-Z]{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4}"
```

**However, this return False,**

```
select "1 Week Ending Jan 14, 2018" rlike "^\\d+ week ending [a-z, A-Z]{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4}"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spark is using the standard Scala regex library, so you can inline the processing flags in the pattern, for example **(?i)** for case-insensitive:

```
spark.sql("""select "1 Week Ending Jan 14, 2018" rlike "(?i)^\\d+ week ending [a-z, A-Z]{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4}"""").show()
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1 Week Ending Jan 14, 2018 RLIKE (?i)^\d+ week ending [a-z, A-Z]{3} \d{2}, \d{4}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                            true|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```