# spark Apply filter multiple times

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need your help in designing and code template (if possible) on the below task in SCALA + SPARK.

- file 1: It is csv file with a "id" + "name" +"description" columns.

  ```
         id,name,description
         1,a,first post in stack overflow
         2,b,second post in stack overflow 
         3,c,third post in stack overflow
         2a,b,seconds post in stack overflow 
         4,b,never posted in stack overflow
  ```
- file 2: It is also csv file having "Keyword" + "value" column

  ```
         keyword,value
         second,1234
         never post,0000
  ```

Requirement:

Search file2:keyword in file1:description, on matching concatenate file1:*, file2:"keyword" "matching_percentage" (calculate it) and file2: "value", write output csv.

- output: new csv id,name,description,keyword,match_percentage,value

  ```
         1,a,first post in stack overflow,none,00,none
         2,b,second post in stack overflow,second,x%,1234
         3,c,third post in stack overflow,none,00,none
         2a,b,seconds post in stack overflow,second,x-%,1234 
         4,b,never posted in stack overflow,never post,y%,0000
  ```

I tried sub-string match in spark sql

```
select a.all_col,b.all_col from file1 a left join file2 b on a.description like concat ('%',b.keyword,'%')
```

but it is taking a lot of time (more than 50 min) due to Cartisan join. file1 has 10 million records and file2 has 500 records. I have not figured out matching_percentage calculation yet.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Written in Python but exactly the same rules apply http://stackoverflow.com/q/33168970/1560062

Comment: Hello, Many thanks for the reference.. tokenizing the document_text will split text to words, but for instance there are multiple words in a row in the keyword column,  then it is not matching.