# Cassandra & Spark : how to avoid Cartesian Product (Jaccard)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, user-defined-functions

here's my problem

I have two tables (10M and 25 millions lines). I want to compare the addresses of these two tables.

My solution was to create an UDF(adress1, adress2) (using Jaccard)

```
String joinSql = "SELECT "
                    + "a.name, a.firstame, Jaccard(a.adress1,b.adress2) as jaccard "
                    + "FROM tmp_tableA as a, tmp_tableB as b "
                    + "where (Jaccard(a.adress1,b.adress.2) > 0.8);


System.out.println(joinSql);
Dataset<Row> dfr = spark.sql(joinSql);
```

It works but it takes ages. How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

[`MinHashLSH`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#minhash-for-jaccard-distance) can be used for `approxSimilarityJoins` roughly equivalent to Jaccard distance.

You can check:

- [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#minhash-for-jaccard-distance)
- [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/MinHashLSH.html)

for details.

My answer to [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/8371915) shows how you can prepare data.