# Pyspark levenshtein Join error

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I want to perform a join based on Levenshtein distance.

I have 2 tables:

1. `Data`: Which is a CSV in HDFS file repository. one of the columns is Disease `description`, 15K rows.
2. `df7_ct_map`: a table I call from Hive. one of the columns is Disease `Indication`, 20K rows.

I'm trying to join both tables by matching each description with the indication (they are text descriptions of sicknesses). Ideally they need to be the same, but if both texts are different I wish to select matching text containing the maximum number of common words.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import levenshtein  
joinedDF = df7_ct_map.join( Data, levenshtein(df7_ct_map("description"), 
Data("Indication")) < 3)
joinedDF.show(10)
```

The problem is `Data` is a `DataFrame` which is why I obtain the following error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
in engine
----> 1 joinedDF = df7_ct_map.join( Data, levenshtein(df7_ct_map("description"), Data("Indication")) < 3)

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Some advice? Can I use Fuzzywuzzy package? If so, how?

Comment: Should be `df7_ct_map["description"]` not `df7_ct_map("description")`. Same for the other one: `Data["Indication"]` not `Data("Indication")`. I would also recommend https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/8371915

Comment: Thank you ! I will try replicate some best practices from your recommendation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of joining using this the other option is as below

```
newDF=df1.join(df2,levenshtein(df1['description'], df2['description']) < 3)
```

This will allow a difference of at most 2 character while joining the 2 data frames.

might this is helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to include the levenshtein distance value in the resulting dataframe?