# how do I calculate the Minhash Signature of a given characteristic matrix using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, minhash

I have a `DataSet` as follows:

```
+----+---------+-------------------------+
|key |value    |vector                   |
+----+---------+-------------------------+
|key0|[a, d]   |(5,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])      |
|key1|[c]      |(5,[1],[1.0])            |
|key2|[b, d, e]|(5,[0,3,4],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|key3|[a, c, d]|(5,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+----+---------+-------------------------+
```

The `vector` part of this dataset is what is called the "characteristic matrix", and it represents "which document contains which element". Let me write the characteristic matrix out using a format that is easier on eyes:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|element | doc0 | doc1 | doc2 | doc3 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|   d    |   1  |  0   |  1   |  1   |
|   c    |   0  |  1   |  0   |  1   |
|   a    |   1  |  0   |  0   |  1   |
|   b    |   0  |  0   |  1   |  0   |
|   e    |   0  |  0   |  1   |  0   |  
+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

If you look carefully, you can see that `key0` maps to `doc0`, which contains element `a` and `d`, that is why it has a vector given by `(5,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])` (the vector is the column under `doc0`. Note the *characteristic matrix* itself does not contain the `element` column and the first row, they are there just to make the reading easier.

Now, my goal is to use `N` hash functions to get the **Minhash signature** of this characteristic matrix.

For example, let `N = 2`, in other words, two Hash functions are used, and let us also say these two hash functions are given below:

```
(x + 1) % 5
(3x + 1) % 5
```

and `x` is the row number in the characteristic matrix. After using these two hash functions, I am expecting the "minhash signature matrix" looks like this:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|        | doc0 | doc1 | doc2 | doc3 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|   h1   |   1  |  3   |  0   |  1   |
|   h2   |   0  |  2   |  0   |  0   |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

Now, using Spark Java, how do I specify these two hash functions that I would like to use, and then how do I generate the above RDD from the given dataset (at the begging of this question)? In real test case, I would probably use about 1000 hash functions, but understanding how to use 2 is good enough for now.

I have been searching and reading the Spark document, but just seems to be quite difficult to get a handler on this. Any hints/guidance will be greatly helpful to me.

Thank you in advance!

Now, I did look at the documentation and I have the following code:

```
<pre>
    List<Tuple2<String, String[]>> data  = Arrays.asList(
            new Tuple2<>("key0", new String [] {"a", "d"}),
            new Tuple2<>("key1", new String [] {"c"}),
            new Tuple2<>("key2", new String [] {"b", "d", "e"}),
            new Tuple2<>("key3", new String [] {"a", "c", "d"})
    );
    JavaPairRDD<String, String[]> rdd = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(jsc.parallelize(data));
    rdd.values().foreach(new VoidFunction<String[]>() {
        public void call(String[] rows) throws Exception {
            for ( int i = 0; i < rows.length; i ++ ) {
                System.out.print(rows[i] + "|");                    
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    });

    StructType schema = StructType.fromDDL("key string, value array<String>");
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(
            rdd.map((Function<Tuple2<String, String[]>, Row>) value -> RowFactory.create(value._1(), value._2())),
            schema
    );
    df.show(false);

    CountVectorizer vectorizer = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("value").setOutputCol("vector").setBinary(false);
    Dataset<Row> matrixDoc = vectorizer.fit(df).transform(df);

    MinHashLSH mh = new MinHashLSH()
      .setNumHashTables(5)
      .setInputCol("vector")
      .setOutputCol("hashes");

    MinHashLSHModel model = mh.fit(matrixDoc);
    model.transform(matrixDoc).show(false);
```

```
here is what I got:
+----+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|key |value    |vector                   |hashes                                                                                 |
+----+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|key0|[a, d]   |(5,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])      |[[7.57939931E8], [-1.974869772E9], [-1.974047307E9], [4.95314097E8], [7.01119548E8]]   |
|key1|[c]      |(5,[2],[1.0])            |[[-2.031299587E9], [-1.758749518E9], [-4.86208737E8], [1.247220523E9], [1.702128832E9]]|
|key2|[b, d, e]|(5,[0,3,4],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|[[-1.278435698E9], [-1.542629264E9], [-1.974047307E9], [4.95314097E8], [-1.59182918E9]]|
|key3|[a, c, d]|(5,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|[[-2.031299587E9], [-1.974869772E9], [-1.974047307E9], [4.95314097E8], [7.01119548E8]] |
+----+---------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I have no idea how to explain the result... what hash functions are used by Spark? do I have a control of what these functions are? How I can then hash the result to different buckets so the documents in the same buckets are the "same" documents? After all, we do not want to do pair-wise comparison...

Comment: Have you seen https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinHashLSH?

Comment: I did, and just could not figure it out... guess I would love to see more details..

Comment: Docs have Java examples https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#lsh-algorithms

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I edited my original questions with more information... I guess it is just a little learning curve here. thanks again for the help!

Comment: Not a problem. You can also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/8371915