# Efficient alphanumeric searching sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have in a Spark data frame with 10 million rows, where each row represents an alpha numeric string indicating id of a user, example:
`602d38c9-7077-4ea1-bc8d-af5c965b4e85` my objective is to check if another id like  `aaad38c9-7087-4ef1-bc8d-af5c965b4e85` is present in the 10 million list.

I would want to do it efficiently and not search all 10 million records, every single time a search happens. Example can I sort my records alphabetically and ask SparkR to search only within records that begin with `a` instead of the universe to speed up search and make it computationally efficient?

Any solutions primarily using **SparkR** if not then any Spark solution would be helpful

Comment: Your requirements indicate you need rather need a search engine than ETL tool like Spark.

Comment: Will partitioning help? If yes can you please share a directional code?

Comment: [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/8371915)

Answer (score -1):

You can use rlike which is for regex search within a dataframe column.

```
df.filter($"foo".rlike("regex"))
```

Or You can index spark dataframe into solr which will definitely search your string within few milliseconds.
https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr

Comment: `filter` doesn't really satisfy the condition to _do it efficiently and not search all 10 million records_, does it?