# SparkR: levenshtein Fuzzy string matching between 2 variables from 2 Spark dataframes

Tags: r, apache-spark, levenshtein-distance, sparkr, sparklyr

I have 2 Spark dataframes

```
library(SparkR); library(magrittr)

df1 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(var1 = c("rat", "cat", "bat")))
df2 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(var2 = c("cat3", "bat1", "dog", "toy")))
```

I need to fuzzy match different lengthed var1 and var2 from different Spark DataFrames df1 and df2 using **SparkR's levenshtein** function so that the desired output becomes.

```
desired_df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(var2 = c("cat3", "bat1", "dog", "toy"),
                                  var3 = c("cat", "bat", NA_character_, NA_character_)))
```

I started with the following code:

```
df3 <- df2 %>% SparkR::mutate(dist = levenshtein(df2$var2, df1$var1))
```

but got stuck with errors:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) var1#176 missing from var2#178 in operator !Project [var2#178, levenshtein(var2#178, var1#176) AS dist#181].;;
!Project [var2#178, levenshtein(var2#178, var1#176) AS dist#181]
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is to reference columns from a table not present in the execution plan.

Adding `crossJoin` would fix that:

```
dist_df <- df1 %>%
  crossJoin(df2) %>% 
  withColumn("dist", levenshtein(df1$var1, df2$var2)) 
dist_df %>% head()
```

```
  var1 var2 dist              
1  rat cat3    2
2  rat bat1    2
3  rat  dog    3
4  rat  toy    3
5  cat cat3    1
6  cat bat1    2
```

From here you could use standard methods ([How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33878370)) to find the closest match, for example:

```
best_matches <- dist_df %>% 
  groupBy("var2") %>% 
  agg(struct(dist_df$dist, dist_df$var1) %>% min() %>% alias("match"))

threshold <- 1  # Maximum match distance to keep

result <- best_matches %>% 
  select(
    best_matches$var2, 
    when(best_matches$match.dist <= threshold, best_matches$match.var1) %>% 
      alias("var1"))

result %>% head()
```

```
  var2 var1
1  dog <NA>
2 bat1  bat
3 cat3  cat
4  toy <NA>
```

Please keep in mind that this approach is very inefficient. Spark provides better options ([Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672)), but these are not exposed in SparkR yet, and only partially implemented in `sparklyr`.

If you want to keep all records, not matter the quality, just remove `when`:

```
best_matches %>% select(best_matches$var2, best_matches$match.var1) %>% head()
```

```
  var2 var1
1  dog  bat
2 bat1  bat
3 cat3  cat
4  toy  bat
```