# Jaccard Similarity between lines of text Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, similarity

I need to compute the Jaccard similarity of all pairs of lines of text. I will want in output only the pairs with a similarity higher than 80%.
In the past I've studied Hadoop MapReduce framework and that is how I would solve this with map and reduce functions:

```
map(lineID, text):
    for each word in text:
         emit(word, (len(text), lineID))

reduce(word, list(v)):
    if len(list(v)) < 2:
        do nothing
    else 
        for each pair ((len1, 1), (len2, 2)):
             emit ((1, 2, len, len2), 1)

map(k, v):
    emit (k, v)

reduce(k, v):
    similarity = len(v)/(k[2]+k[3]-len(v))
    if similarity > 0.80
         emit((k[0], k[1]), similarity)
```

Now I need to implement this pseudocode in PySpark, but I am a little bit stuck. All I managed to do is the first map, like:

```
def mapping(line):
    length = len(line.split())-1
    jobID = line.split()[0]
    return (length, jobID)

c = textFile.map(lambda line: [(c, (mapping(line))) for c in line.split()[1:]])
```

I am not considering the first word because that word is the lineID. This is another doubt I have, how to get the indexes of the lines of the input text? 
How are the tasks assigned to the workers? I am very confused about the way Apache Spark works.

Do you have any suggestion about which methods could I use, and in which order for achieving the result I get in MapReduce?

Comment: [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your data is very large, the simplest and easiest approach may also be the fastest. Let's divide and conquer the problem:

1. Get a dataframe of all pairs of lines using `crossJoin`.
2. Remove the rows where the left hand line is the same as the right hand line as you don't care about self comparisons.
3. Use a simple UDF jaccard(left, right) to return the Jaccard similarity.
4. Filter by similarity > 0.8

I use Spark through Scala so I'll give you the Scala code for this; the Python DSL should be very similar.

```
val lines = spark.read.text(...)
lines.alias("lhs").crossJoin(lines.alias("rhs"))
  .where($"lhs.value" =!= $"rhs.value")
  .withColumn("similarity", jaccard($"lhs.value", $"rhs.value"))
  .where($"similarity" > 0.8)
```