# How Can I get the nearest neighbor matrix from 1,000,000 rows and 20,000 features?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, knn, databricks

I am in serious trouble.
I want to calculate the relationship of ten million records, but processing stops because Spark's memory is insufficient.
Ten million documents are created by TF - Hashing to create 20,000 - dimensional features.
First of all, I tried '- Approximate similarity join', but the calculation did not converge.
Next, I attempted to try KNN of scikit-learn, but when I brought all the data to Driver, memory was overflowing.
Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify your abbreviations?   Is it TF - tensorflow?  KNN - k-nearest neighbor

Comment: Take a look at [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/10465355)

Comment: kNN is not part of the native Spark MLlib and ml packages. LinkedIn has published a kNN implementation for Spark: https://github.com/linkedin/scanns

Comment: @MichaelWest TF means Text Frequency, sorry. KNN is k-nearest neighbor.

Comment: @user10465355
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @andrew
Thank you for you kindness.
I'm trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearest Neighbor does not seem to be part of Spark's MLLib.  Options I think of are to find a distributed spark implementation or find a tensorflow implementation

Are on Databricks?  recent versions support distributed Tensorflow.  I've have run larger volumes than yours on a single node Databricks Tensorflow cluster.

quick searching turned up these
* [tensorflow nearest neighbor](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/nearest_neighbor.py)
* [spark nearest neighbor](https://github.com/saurfang/spark-knn)

Note that I have not tried these myself.

Comment: Finally, I could solve it with Spark's MLLib's Jaccard and Minhash methods.
thx for your kindeness.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out.  Thanks for letting us know!