# LSH in Scala and Python API

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was following this SO post [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938672/efficient-string-matching-in-apache-spark) to get some string matching using LSH algorithm. For some reason getting results thru python API, but not in Scala. I don't see really where what is missing in Scala code.

Here below are the both codes:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, NGram, HashingTF, MinHashLSH

query = spark.createDataFrame(["Bob Jones"], "string").toDF("text")

db = spark.createDataFrame(["Tim Jones"], "string").toDF("text")

model = Pipeline(stages=[
    RegexTokenizer(
        pattern="", inputCol="text", outputCol="tokens", minTokenLength=1
    ),
    NGram(n=3, inputCol="tokens", outputCol="ngrams"),
    HashingTF(inputCol="ngrams", outputCol="vectors"),
    MinHashLSH(inputCol="vectors", outputCol="lsh")
]).fit(db)

db_hashed = model.transform(db)
query_hashed = model.transform(query)

model.stages[-1].approxSimilarityJoin(db_hashed, query_hashed, 0.75).show()
```

And it returns:

> ```
> > +--------------------+--------------------+-------+ |            datasetA|            datasetB|distCol|
> > +--------------------+--------------------+-------+ |[Tim Jones, [t, i...|[Bob Jones, [b, o...|    0.6|
> > +--------------------+--------------------+-------+
> ```

However Scala returns nothing, and here is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer
val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setPattern("").setInputCol("text").setMinTokenLength(1).setOutputCol("tokens")
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.NGram
val ngram = new NGram().setN(3).setInputCol("tokens").setOutputCol("ngrams")
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF
val vectorizer = new HashingTF().setInputCol("ngrams").setOutputCol("vectors")
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{MinHashLSH, MinHashLSHModel}
val lsh = new MinHashLSH().setInputCol("vectors").setOutputCol("lsh")
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, ngram, vectorizer, lsh))
val query = Seq("Bob Jones").toDF("text")
val db = Seq("Tim Jones").toDF("text")
val model = pipeline.fit(db)
val dbHashed = model.transform(db)
val queryHashed = model.transform(query)
model.stages.last.asInstanceOf[MinHashLSHModel].approxSimilarityJoin(dbHashed, queryHashed, 0.75).show
```

I am using Spark 3.0, I know its a test, but can't really test it on different version. And I doubt there is a bug like that :)

Comment: I've found when I added setNumHashTables(10), then Scala code returns me results. But still dont understand why in python resturns results without that.

Comment: Also found that Scala code works without setting Number of Hash tables in Spark 2.4.4, so apparently something was changed in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

This code will work in Spark 3.0.1 if you set numHashTables correctly.

```
val lsh = new MinHashLSH().setInputCol("vectors").setOutputCol("lsh").setNumHashTables(3)
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.