# PySpark - Apply function on re-partitioned batches

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I am doing [fuzzy string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938672/efficient-string-matching-in-apache-spark) using `MinHashLSH` and `approxSimilarityJoin` on 500 billion pairs. It is too big for my current cluster setup, thus, I want to run it in batches

I want to partition the data, and run `approxSimilarityJoin` on each partition iteratively such that my cluster can handle it.

My current function is:

```
matched_df = model.stages[-1].approxSimilarityJoin(df1, df2, 1.0, "confidence")
```

But I am stuck on how to combine `repartition`, `foreachPartition` and `approxSimilarityJoin`.

I think it should be something like:

```
df1.repartition(100).foreachPartition(batch : model.stages[-1].approxSimilarityJoin(batch, df2, 1.0, "confidence"))
```

but I have the wrong syntax. What is the correct syntax for `foreachPartition`?

Comment: What do you mean by this set being too big for you cluster? Are you getting out of memory exceptions? Running this iteratively is not going to make a performance difference.

Comment: Yes, I am running out of memory because of how approxSimilarityJoin() works. Given two lists, it creates all pairs of each element of both lists and calculate a distance between both element of the pair. I don't need to calculate all pairs all at once, I can do that iteratively in batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that using `foreachParition`.
`foreachParition` takes a function that will be run on the executors and passes into it actual data, not a dataframe (it's an action that will trigger processing, like .collect or .write, not just a transformation definition). And if you wanted to recreate a dataframe from this passed in set, this also won't work as there is no spark context available on the worker itself. Conceptually dataframe is not a table but a lazy-evaluated definition of a transformation.

What you can do, however, is just split the `df1` using Spark. If there is no key on which you can filter the DataFrame, you can just do it using `randomSplit`, e.g.:

```
df.randomSplit((0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), seed=42)
```

The result of this operation is a list of DataFrames

```
[DataFrame[date: string, text: string],
 DataFrame[date: string, text: string],
 DataFrame[date: string, text: string],
 DataFrame[date: string, text: string],
 DataFrame[date: string, text: string]]
```

over which you can iterate using regular Python

```
dfs = df.randomSplit((0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), seed=42)
for df in dfs:
    matched_df = model.stages[-1].approxSimilarityJoin(df, df2, 1.0, "confidence")
    do_something_with(matched_df)
```

To split your dataset this way into 100 parts, you can generate the weights tuple:

```
df.randomSplit(tuple([0.01 for x in range (100)]), seed=42)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!