# How to join 2 dataframes in Spark based on a wildcard/regex condition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2`.
Suppose there is a `location` column in `df1` which may contain a regular URL or a URL with a wildcard, e.g.:

- stackoverflow.com/questions/*
- *.cnn.com
- cnn.com/*/politics

The seconds dataframe `df2` has `url` field which may contain only valid URLs without wildcards.

I need to join these two dataframes, something like `df1.join(df2, $"location" matches $"url")` if there was magic `matches` operator in join conditions.

After some googling I still don't see a way how to achieve this. How would you approach solving such problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There exist "magic" matches operator - it is called `rlike`

```
val df1 = Seq("stackoverflow.com/questions/.*$","^*.cnn.com$", "nn.com/*/politics").toDF("location")
val df2 = Seq("stackoverflow.com/questions/47272330").toDF("url")

df2.join(df1, expr("url rlike location")).show
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 url|            location|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|stackoverflow.com...|stackoverflow.com...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

however there are some caveats:

- Patterns have to be proper regular expressions, anchored in case of leading / trailing wildcards.
- It is executed with Cartesian product ([How can we JOIN two Spark SQL dataframes using a SQL-esque "LIKE" criterion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33168970/8371915)):

  ```
  == Physical Plan ==
  BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Inner, url#217 RLIKE location#211
  :- *Project [value#215 AS url#217]
  :  +- *Filter isnotnull(value#215)
  :     +- LocalTableScan [value#215]
  +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
     +- *Project [value#209 AS location#211]
        +- *Filter isnotnull(value#209)
           +- LocalTableScan [value#209]
  ```

It is possible to filter candidates using method I described in [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/8371915)

Comment: Thanks, I've added an extra step to replace "\*" with ".*" and add anchors so was able to solve my problem

Comment: rlike just for dataframes ? Do you know a similar way but for RDDs ?

Comment: Thank you in advance for answer, this rlike operation not working with java spark. Programmatically also when I create join Expression as functions.col(“url”).rlike(functions.col(“location”)), it gives compile time error as it except literal value.

Comment: @MahendraKapadne That's expected. I intentionally uses `expr` here. There is no `(Column, Column) => Column` variant.

Comment: @user8371915 yes you are correct but if I write functions.expr(“url rlike location”); then it compiles but it throws runtime exception. I am stuck here to use spark joins with java ☹️

Comment: @MahendraKapadne What is the exception?

Comment: Hi Can you please tell me an equivalent query for HIVE as well.

Comment: This doesnt work if the string contains parenthesis. The `rlike` method neglects those. How do we include parentheses when using `rlike` ?