# PySpark Join for String data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp

I m used to join tables in Pyspark using the following:

```
joined_data = users_data.join(shopping_list, users_data["name"] == 
shopping_list["users_nm"], "left_outer") 
joined_data .show(10)
```

The names and users_nm are strings but they might contain some unnecessary information. This is not giving me a good result. As an example :

- name = **Lepirudin** is identical to natural hirudin except for
  substitution of leucine for isoleucine at the N-terminal end of the
  molecule and the absence of a sulfate group on the tyrosine at
  position 63. It is produced via yeast cells. Bayer ceased the
  production of lepirudin (Refludan) effective May 31, 2012.
- users_nm =  {""description"": ""Milrinone may increase the
  anticoagulant

  activities of **Lepirudin**.""

These 2 names are very differents but they mean the same thing : Lepirudin.

I am thinking of using livenshtein distance ...

Suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: And possible duplicate of [How can we JOIN two Spark SQL dataframes using a SQL-esque “LIKE” criterion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33168970/8371915)

Comment: Not duplicated since I don't have a keyword list. This is different subject since the extended name can com from both dataframes.